# import QML Module from qrc file

Tags: qml

Is it possible to have a module inside a qrc file and then make that module available to multiple projects?
I know how to build a module (not in qrc file)  into a local project and have managed to reuse this module in another project.

I plan to create a project to contain the module and compile it into a qrc file  - 
What sort of project should it be - Qt Creator only offers qml application
How do I then import the module from the qrc file?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by module? Why exactly `qrc` and not plugin, what would be right? What is your _real_ target?

Comment: The idea is that I want a module that contains custom controls and then to have that module available to multiple projects. Is a plugin going to be a better approach? I wanted to be able to import the module in the same way as the standard QML modules (import QtQuick.Controls 1.3 for example)

Comment: @GrahamSim as you indicate the correct way is to create a plugin, this is how Qt does it with the standard module

Comment: OK thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: So I have a plugin that has generated a dll - now how do I import types from this dll and how do I make QML aware of it?

Comment: You can start from [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have to create a qt plugin